# Link to sorting questions by new, active broken in Stack Overflow for Teams, but not for main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, sorting, question-lists

If I go to `stackoverflow.com/c/myteamname/questions`, and click on the link for "Newest", "Active", etc., I get taken to `stackoverflow.com/c/myteamname/posts?tab=Newest`, where I get a "Page Not Found" error:

[image: Page not found]

Workaround: If I fix the link to replace "posts" with "questions", then it works fine.

This doesn't happen on the main site, however.

Comment: When I click on "Newest", "Active", etc. I am taken to `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<teamname>/questions?tab=Active` and not `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<teamname>/posts?tab=Active` as you said... So, no repro on my side... On the other hand if I manually change "questions" to "posts" in the URL then I get this error...

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine I have 3 Teams and 1 of them exhibits this issue. Comparing all of them, 2 Teams are on the Basic tier and don't have this issue, but 1 Team is on the Business tier and has this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up.

Our devs have fixed this already, the pages should work as expected now :)